# Possible data race between writes to the same address in memory

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, thread-safety

Consider the following snippet.

```
T data;
T* ptr1 = &data;
T* ptr2 = &data;
*ptr1 = ...;
std::thread thread([ptr2]() {
    *ptr2 = ...;
});
thread.join();
```

Question: does it introduce a data race?

My thoughts: since `ptr1` and `ptr2` are different variables, the assignment and the capture-by-value are subject to reordering. Thus, the data race is there.

Is this correct?

Comment: How can it? The thread is spawned after the first modification. That execution is still sequenced.

Comment: @StoryTeller Aha, that's what I missed! Spawning a thread introduces at least a memory fence. Correct?

Comment: _"The completion of the invocation of the constructor [of the thread] synchronizes-with (as defined in std::memory_order) the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f on the new thread of execution._" from here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Comment: @RichardCritten but doesn't this just mean that the beginning of the thread's execution happens *after* the lambda is constructed. And since the assignment on line 4 and the lambda's constructor are unsequenced (or am I missing smth here?), this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus - It's actually more basic than that. `*ptr1 = ...;` and the declaration of `thread` are [two full expressions sequenced in a particular order](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#16). One has to happen in full before the other according to the abstract machine itself. A compiler can't really do a transformation that would change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thread creation implies a *happens before* relation, i.e., there is no data race in the given code. In fact, the assignment to `*ptr1` actually happened before the next statement anyway.  If you reordered the code to have the assignment to `*ptr1` after the thread creation you’d have a data race: it does not matter which pointer reference is used to access an object to create a data race.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "In fact, the assignment to *ptr1 actually happened before the next statement anyway"? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Within one thread the operations are sequenced at the end of each full-expression. Even though the compiler/CPU may reorder operations doing so is only allowed if the semantics of the program isn’t changed. Introduction of a data race would be such a semantic change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a race in here. Until you create the new thread the program runs single-threaded, thus the order of execution will be as written by you.

[Here's](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) an explanation about memory ordering at compile time.

And a nice quote from this page:

`The cardinal rule of memory reordering, which is universally followed by compiler developers and CPU vendors, could be phrased as follows:
Thou shalt not modify the behavior of a single-threaded program.`